# Is $Q(u,u)$ (also $\langle u,Av\rangle$) considered a scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cross-product

Can you tell me if this is a good answer?: Let $u,v$ be vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $A$ be an indefinite $n×n$ matrix (whose determinants of the main submatrices are both positive and negative). I thought that given that "$Av$" is actually a vector which a matrix has been applied to, we can consider $Av$ as $v$ in new coordinates imposed by the matrix $A$, also $\langle u,Av\rangle$ is a normal scalar product.

Is this a good point or I'm completely wrong?

Comment: I can't understand if your answer is a good answer because I don't understand the question

Comment: An inner product has the property that $\langle u,  u\rangle = 0\  {\rm iff}\ u = 0$. Does yours satisfy this?

Comment: Omnomnomnom i'll try to explain it again. Let $A$ be a real indefinite matrix. Is $<u,Av>$ a scalar product?

Comment: @ok Got it. Your usage of "also" in parentheses confused me; I thought you were asking two different questions.

Comment: Hi NickD. The vectors $u$ and $v$ were defined just $u,v$=(x,y,z). Also we can't tell if $<u,u> = 0$. We only know that the matrix A is indefinite (positive and negative eigenvalues). $Q(u,u)$ should be the quadratic form $u A u^T$

Comment: Hi Omnomnomnom. $Q(u,u)$ should be the quadratic form $u A u^T$ . As I said to the other user we only know that the matrix $A$ is indefinite and $u$=$(x,y,z)^T$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that scalar product means the same thing as [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) in this context.

The answer to your question is no.  If $A$ is indefinite, then there necessarily exists a vector $v$ such that $Q(v,v) = v^TAv < 0$. In particular, plugging in an eigenvector of $A$ associated with a negative eigenvalue demonstrates this.  Similarly, a positive semidefinite $A$ does not induce a scalar product because there exists a non-zero vector $v$ such that $v^TAv = 0$.

We could apply an argument similar to yours to deduce that for any invertible matrix $M$ (in fact, any matrix with linearly independent columns will do) is such that the function $Q(u,v) = \langle Mu, Mv \rangle$ defines a scalar product. Note that this can be rewritten as $Q(u,v) = u^T (M^TM)v$.

In fact, the following are equivalent:

- $A$ is positive definite,
- $Q(u,v) = u^TAv$ is a scalar product,
- There exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that $A = M^TM$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, may I ask a little detail? Is there a way the indefinite matrix $A$ can be written in the quadratic form?

Comment: Correct, there is no way that an indefinite matrix $A$ can be written in the form $A = M^TM$ (where $M$ has real entries).

Comment: But I remember the question of the test explicitily asking for the quadratic form of matrix $A$.

Comment: @ok $A = M^TM$ is not usually called "the quadratic form of $A$".  Typically, the quadratic form of a matrix $A$ is the function $Q(u,u) = u^TAu$.

Comment: So there is an $A$ such that $Q(u,u)$ = $u^T Au$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. For any quadratic form $Q$, there is an $A$ (in fact a symmetric $A$) such that $Q(u) = u^TAu$.